# Android - How to use DragShadowBuilder?

Tags: android

I am using from `DragShadowBuilder.java`, this class is for a sample.

I don't know how I can use in my `Activity`, What parameters I should send to `constructor` of `DrawableDragShadowBuilder`:

```
public class DrawableDragShadowBuilder extends DragShadowBuilder {
    private Drawable mDrawable;

    public DrawableDragShadowBuilder(View view, Drawable drawable) {
        super(view);
        // Set the drawable and apply a green filter to it
        mDrawable = drawable;
        mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point touchPoint) {
        // Fill in the size
        shadowSize.x = mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        shadowSize.y = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        // Fill in the location of the shadow relative to the touch.
        // Here we center the shadow under the finger.
        touchPoint.x = mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
        touchPoint.y = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;

        mDrawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, shadowSize.x, shadowSize.y));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw the shadow view onto the provided canvas
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Thank's a lot.

Comment: A much easier way, you can instantiate `DragShadowBuilder` and pass the view instance which you want to be dragged in its constructor.. If you want I can give an example of using it as an answer ?

Comment: Yes yes , I need .I don't know What parameters I should send to constructor of DrawableDragShadowBuilder .

Comment: Don't  use the above example... instead use a much simple one , I will post if for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `View` which you want to drag, in the constructor of `DragShadowBuilder`

```
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
```

And then start the drag using:

```
view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
```

Here is the complete example following this excellent [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
  findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
 findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
 findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
 findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
 findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
 findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
 findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
 findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

 }

private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
 }
} 

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
    // do nothing
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    owner.removeView(view);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
    container.addView(view);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
  default:
    break;
    }
  return true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you have any sample for my code get me link . Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I find a sample for my problem :

My `StartActivity.java` :

```
    public class StartActivity extends Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
            findViewById(R.id.imgv).setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DrawableDragShadowBuilder(v, 
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, ((ImageView) v).getDrawable(), 0);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And `activity_start.xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```